# C# RhinoMock Nested Mapping Tables Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Below are three tables one of them is Master table and two are relation with each one. while doing unit testing I am not able to get the few test cases scenario based on the my business logic.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDepartment> EmployeeDepartments { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDepartment
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee{ get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDepartment> EmployeeDepartments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my unit test method code:

```
// Arrange
var employees = new FakeDbSet<Employee>();            
Expect.Call(dataContext.Set<Employee>()).Return(employees).Repeat.Any();

// Act
--Code for Service Method

// Assert
var actualEmpl = this.actualEmpl;
Assert.IsTrue(actualEmpl.EmployeeDepartment.Any(w => w.Department.DName == "ABC"));
```

> My problem here is I always get "w.Department.DName" is null. Please
>   help me to get it resolve.
>
> Department is master table list (min 20 rows) and EmployeeDepartment
>   can only have single or couple of records.

Comment: These are models. There is no business logic here. If you are testing `business logic`, please add it to the listing. To unit test models, use reflection to assert that correct properties with correct data types and names are present on the models.

Comment: I'm not sure how is it related to mocking... are you trying to Mock your DB or object model? Can you provide more details on what you want to mock and what you want to actually test?